# regex - swap two phrases around

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Python 3. Each line is constructed of a piece of text, then a pipe symbol, then a second piece of text.
I want to swap the two pieces of text around and remove the pipe.
This is the code so far:

```
p = re.compile('^(.*) \| (.*)$', re.IGNORECASE)
mytext = p.sub(r'\2\1', mytext)
```

Yet for some reason that I can't work out, it is not matching.
A sample of the text it should be matching is (ironically):

```
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIKdKCQnbNo) | [Regular Expressions 101 - YouTube]
```

and should end up like:

```
[The Field Expedient Pump Drill - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QDXUxTrlRw)
```

(in other words, the code is formatting the links into the format expected of a markdown converter).

Here is the full code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re, os

def create_text(myinputfile):
    with open(myinputfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        mytext = infile.read()
    return mytext

def reg_replace(mytext):
    p = re.compile('^(.*) \| (.*)$', re.IGNORECASE)
    mytext = p.sub(r'\2\1', mytext)
return mytext

def write_out(mytext, myfinalfile):
    with open(myfinalfile, 'w') as myoutfile:
        myoutfile.write(mytext)

def main():
    mytext = create_text('out.md')
    mytext = reg_replace(mytext)
    write_out(mytext, 'out1.md')
    os.rename("out.md", "out_original.md")
    os.rename("out1.md", "out.md")

main()
```

Comment: Your regex works fine. [Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY6xD5/2). It's probably an issue with your code.

Comment: Typo: `return mytext` needs to be indented in your `reg_replace`

Comment: @4castle: yes, I sometimes find the regex engine a bit fiddly and I've had a similar problem before - that's why the output is a raw string. Indent - return mytext is correctly indented in the original code, it's a formatting issue when I copied it across to here. Well spotted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you. (View demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hW2kR9/2))

```
(\S+)\s*\|\s*(.+)
```

Sub with:

```
 \2\1
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I'm missing something here, but why not just use `re.match` with groups instead of `re.sub`?:

```
import re

p = re.compile('^(.*) \| (.*)$', re.IGNORECASE)
sample = "(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIKdKCQnbNo) | [Regular Expressions 101 - YouTube]"

matches = p.search(sample)

new_string = "{0}{1}".format(matches.group(2), matches.group(1))
print(new_string)
>>> [Regular Expressions 101 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIKdKCQnbNo)
```

Comment: A good answer. Unfortunately as it stands the code will only return one match - I'd have to loop through each line and use each line as "sample"; there's about a thousand lines to process. With regards to re.match - from the Python documentation: "Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line."

Comment: ahh, okay. sorry!